# Initializing an GoogleApiClient object

Tags: android, cloud, google-play-services

I want to use Cloud Save in my application but I can't find any example code. My first problem is the initialization and this is what I tried:

```
GoogleApiClient.Builder apiBuild = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext());
GoogleApiClient api = apiBuild.build();
```

The error says that I should first add at least one API so i guess I should use

```
apiBuild.addApi(API);
```

But I don't know what API I should use for Cloud Save, does anyone?
It would be great if you could give me a complete example code.

Answer (score 0):

[According to this link](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/cloudsave)...

---

The new **Google Play Games Saved Games** service introduced in **July 2014** offers improved functionality for saving game state information and visually displaying player game progression. Game developers are highly encouraged to **migrate from the Cloud Save (AppState) service to the new Saved Games (Snapshot) service as soon as possible**. A new version of Cloud Save is coming soon.

---

At the bottom of the link, it takes you to a page where you can use this new services on android.
[Here is the link.](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames)

So it appears that the api you should be adding is `apiBuild.addApi(Drive.API);`

Comment: Is the service available yet?

Comment: @Mantech Yeah I think so. I don't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: Have you ever used this service? I'm following all the instructions of the link you gave me but I get an error I don't know how to resolve when I start the Activity

Comment: @Mantech Unfortunately no, but I think you should post another question of that error.